# Immersive AR mode in development build of Android Chromium

Tags: android, chromium, aframe, arcore

I want to use immersive AR mode in my build of Android Chromium.

I built Chromium Android as the default `MonochromePublic.apk`. After installing the APK on a Pixel XL, AR mode seems not to activate. However, the published Chrome Prod/Dev/Beta/Canary all enter AR mode just fine on the same page https://aframe.io/examples. Did I miss a build flag somewhere?

Has anyone building Android Chromium had the same issue with immersive AR?
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md

```
Chromium    83.0.4088.0 (Developer Build) unknown (32-bit)
Revision    f71e417d43f4f695028e96b0c8b16df1d6da60eb-refs/heads/master@{#750950}
OS  Android 10; Pixel XL Build/QP1A.191005.007.A3
Google Play services    SDK=12451000; Installed=201216037; Access=3p
JavaScript  V8 8.3.9
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Pixel XL) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4088.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
Command Line    --use-mobile-user-agent --top-controls-show-threshold=0.5 --top-controls-hide-threshold=0.5 --use-mobile-user-agent --enable-viewport --validate-input-event-stream --enable-longpress-drag-selection --touch-selection-strategy=direction --main-frame-resizes-are-orientation-changes --disable-composited-antialiasing --enable-dom-distiller --flag-switches-begin --enable-webgl-draft-extensions --enable-features=WebXRIncubations --flag-switches-end
Executable Path No such file or directory
Profile Path    /data/user/0/org.chromium.chrome/app_chrome/Default
Variations  AllPassiveMixedContentAutoupgrade:Enabled
AndroidInProductHelpContextualSearchPromotePanelOpen:PromotePanelOpeningExperiment
AndroidInProductHelpContextualSearchPromoteTap:PromoteTapExperiment
AndroidInProductHelpContextualSearchWebSearch:WebSearchExperiment
AndroidInProductHelpDownloadInfoBarDownloadContinuing:Tracking
AndroidInProductHelpDownloadInfoBarDownloadsAreFaster:Tracking
AndroidInProductHelpDownloadPage:Tracking
AndroidInProductHelpDownloadPageScreenshot:EnabledTracking
AndroidInProductHelpDownloadSettings:Tracking
AndroidInProductHelpManualTranslate:Enabled
AndroidInlineUpdateFlowStudy:Enabled_NoNotification
AndroidMediaProcessPriority:ModerateBindingInBackground
AndroidPictureInPictureAPI:Disabled
AndroidSpellChecker:Enabled_NonLowEnd
AndroidSystemTracing:EnablePerfettoSystemTracing
AssumeOverlapAfterFixedOrStickyPosition:Enabled
AsyncDns:Enabled
AutofillKeyboardAccessory:Enabled_Full_20200214
AutofillProfileValidation:EnabledClient_20190211
AutofillServerBehaviors:API_Enabled
BackForwardCache:EnabledForSpecificDomain
BackForwardCacheMemoryControls:Enabled
BackgroundSync:RelyOnAndroidNetworkDetection
BlinkSchedulerPrioritizeCompositingAfterInput:ExplicitSignals_1task_high
BlinkSchedulerVeryHighPriorityForCompositingExperiments:VeryHighPriorityForCompositingAfterDelay100
CSSOMViewScrollCoordinates:EnableCSSOMViewScrollCoordinates
CacheStorageSequence:Enabled1
ChromeDuet:Disabled
ChromeSmartSelection:Enabled_Launch
ChromeStart:Enabled
ContentCapture:ContentCaptureUseTextHolder
ContextualSearch:SuppressionExperiment
DataCompressionProxyPromoVisibility:Enabled
DecodeJpegToYuv:Experiment
DefaultEnableOopRasterization:DefaultEnableOopRasterization
DeprecateFtp:WithoutFtpSupport
DnsOverHttps:Enabled_crbug1006105
DownloadOfflineContentProvider:Enabled
DownloadWithServicificationM77:Enabled_20191111
DownloadsAutoResumptionNative:Enabled
DownloadsLocationChange:Enabled
EphemeralTab:Enabled
ExploreSitesDense:WithDenseBottom
FontSrcLocalMatching:Enabled
FreezeBackgroundTabOnNetworkIdle:enable_1min
GestureNavigation:Enabled
HTTPDangerWarning:enabled
HeapProfiling:Enabled
HistoryServiceAndProfileSyncServiceUseThreadPool:all_enabled_20200129
IdentityDiscIPH:IdentityDiscIPH
InterestFeedContentSuggestions:EnabledUndoableActions
IsolatePasswordSites:Enabled
KeyboardAccessoryPasswordIPH:Password_IPH_Enabled
KeyboardAccessoryPaymentIPH:Payment_IPH_Enabled
LimitReferrerGranularity:Enabled
LoadingPredictorTableConfig:Enabled_300_10
LowPriorityAdProcesses:Enabled0
LowPriorityIframes2:Enabled
LowerJavaScriptPriorityWhenForceDeferred:Enabled_20190905
MetricsAndCrashSampling:InReportingSample
NavigationPredictor:Enabled_Logistic_Precision_15_M79_20191029
OfflineIndicator:EnabledBottom
OfflinePagesCctV2:Enabled
OmniboxAssistantVoiceSearch:Enabled
OmniboxBundledExperimentV1:AndroidExperiments
OmniboxOnDeviceHeadSuggest:Beta_OnDeviceHeadSuggest_Enabled
OmniboxSearchEngineLogo:Enabled
OptimizationTargetPrediction:Enabled
OutOfBlinkCors:Enabled
OverflowIconsForMediaControls:Enabled
PaintHolding:Enabled
PartitionConnectionsByNetworkIsolationKey:PartitionConnectionsAndSSLSessionsAndQuic
PersistentHistograms:EnabledOnDisk5
PreconnectOnDidFinishNavigation:Enabled_3_seconds
PreconnectToSearch:EnabledWithoutStartupDelay
PreviewsLitePageRedirect:Enabled_OverridePH_20190221
PreviewsNoScript:NoScriptWithWhiteList2
ProactivelySwapBrowsingInstance:Enabled
ProactivelyThrottleLowPriorityRequests:Enabled_20190722
ProtoDBSharedMigration:Enabled3
QUIC:Enabled
QueryInOmnibox:Enabled
QuietNotificationPrompts:EnableWithAdaptiveActivation
ReaderModeUI:AdaBoost
RendererSchedulerWakeUpThrottling:RendererSchedulerWakeUpThrottling
ReportSaveDataSavings:Enabled
ReportingAPIAndNetworkErrorLogging:ReportingAndNELEnabled
ResourceLoadingHints:Enabled2
SafeBrowsingAdPopupTrigger:Enabled
SafeBrowsingAdRedirectTrigger:Enabled
SafeBrowsingAdSamplerTrigger:AdSampler_NormalRate
SafeBrowsingAndroid:Enabled
SafeBrowsingCommittedInterstitials:Enabled
SafeBrowsingPasswordProtectionForSavedPasswordsAndroid:Enabled
SafeBrowsingRealTimeUrlLookupEnabledAndroid:Enabled
SafeBrowsingSuspiciousSiteTrigger:Enabled
SafeBrowsingThreatDomDetailsTagAttributes:AdIdentifiers
SameSiteByDefaultCookies_AndroidAw:LaxByDefaultAndNoneRequiresSecure
ScriptStreamingOnPreload:Enabled
ScrollResamplingRollout:Enabled
ServiceGroupImportance:Enabled
ServiceManagerForBackgroundPrefetch:Enabled
ServiceWorkerStartupOptimizations:Enabled_Ui_Ps3
SharedClipboard:Enabled
SplitCacheByNetworkIsolationKey:Enabled_Stable
SqlSkipPreload:Enabled
SubresourceRedirect:Enabled
TabGridLayoutAndroid:Enabled
TabGroupsDragAndDrop:Enabled
TabGroupsQuicklyComparePages:Enabled
TabGroupsTapToSeeAnotherTab:Enabled
TabGroupsYourTabsTogether:Enabled
TabToGTSAnimation:Enabled
TextFragmentAnchor:Enabled_20191216
ThrottleDelayable:MaxDelayable_3g_8_Weight3_20190215
TranslateRankerModelAndroid:Enforcement20170918
TrustedTypes:Enabled
UpdateMenuItem:StorageRequired500
UseInProgressDownloadManagerForDownloadService:Enabled
UseSkiaRenderer:UseSkiaRenderer
V8ConcurrentInlining:Disabled
V8WasmLiftoffMobile:Tiering
VideoCaptureServiceAndroid:Enabled
WebAudioAutoplay:Enabled
```

Viewing the built APK in Android Studio, the `AndroidManifest.xml` seems to include access to ARCore:

```
        <meta-data
            name="com.google.ar.core"
            value="optional" />
```

[Screenshot of AR Mode Activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOISy.png)

Upon click of AR button, console error logged from device inspector:

```
aframe.io/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The specified session configuration is not supported.
Promise.then (async)        
enterVR @   a-scene.js:787
enterAR @   a-scene.js:787
onEnterARButtonClick    @   vr-mode-ui.js:172
(anonymous) @   bind.js:7
(anonymous) @   vr-mode-ui.js:172
```

*UPDATED:* I tried setting  all my `args.gn` flags explicitly, updated with Chrome 84, but the same error occurs:

```
target_os = "android"
target_cpu = "arm64"
current_os = "android"
current_cpu = "arm64"
enable_vr = true
enable_arcore = true
```

Comment: What happens when you visit the examples in: https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/

Comment: On https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/immersive-ar-session.html the `start ar` button throws: `
XRSession creation failed: The specified session configuration is not supported.
(anonymous) @ webxr-button.js:483
Promise.catch (async)
__onXRButtonClick @ webxr-button.js:478
(anonymous) @ webxr-button.js:342`

Comment: See https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/device/vr/buildflags/buildflags.gni - currently, enable_arcore has enable_vr as a prerequisite, though that should be switched on by enable_gvr_services automatically.

Can you run `gn args out/Default --list` and check if enable_arcore is set? Try enabling it in args.gn manually?

Comment: Thanks @klausw! Yes, `gn args out/Default --list` shows enable_arcore = true. I was suspicious that since enable_arcore depends on current_cpu (it was "" in the `gn args` list) that I might need to set it manually. I tried a clean ninja build with the `args.gn` updated above and the same error on AR button click.